# Antilock braking system

Tags: nissan, abs, braking, measurement

The brake pedal of my friend's Nissan Terrano becomes spongy for short period of time while braking over bumps and the braking doesn't seem to slow down the vehicle for a short time.Braking under normal conditions is OK but it's not so on bumps.I was trying to understand why the abs activates on bumps.

What are the methods to determine experimentally when the abs of a car is activated and the duration over which it remains active during braking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about maintenance or repair. This site is for actual problems you are trying to solve. There is a lot of information available on the Internet about ABS theory and workings.

Comment: I'm studying the faulty activation of abs on bumps. I couldn't get any relevant information from the internet about it.

Comment: Then please describe your problem, what vehicle and what you have tried. We can help with that. What you originally posted sounds like homework. Please read **[ask]** to improve your question and your chances of someone helping.

Comment: The brake pedal of my friend's nissan terrano becomes spongy for short period of time while braking over bumps and the braking doesn't seem to slow down the vehicle for a short time.Braking under normal conditions is ok but it's not so on bumps.I was trying to understand why the abs activates on bumps.

Comment: You need to use the [edit] feature to re-write your question above. That way when people click on it, they will see what is going on without having to read comments. I have copied it to your question for you this time. The details make it much better, so I retracted my close vote.

Comment: I'm unable to edit since I don't know what to enter into the edit summary.Should I ask the question once again as shown in the edit

Comment: I've already do it for you this time. The edit summary is just a simple statement of why you edited it. For instance, "Added details" or "Corrected spelling", etc.

Comment: You're welcome. The **[help]** is a great place to learn how the site works.